# How can I use the PHP File api to write raw bytes?

Tags: php, file-io

I want to write a raw byte/byte stream to a position in a file.
This is what I have currently:

```
$fpr = fopen($out, 'r+');
fseek($fpr, 1); //seek to second byte
fwrite($fpr, 0x63); 
fclose($fpr);
```

This currently writes the actually string value of "99" starting at byte offset 1.  IE, it writes bytes "9" and "9".  I just want to write the actual one byte value 0x63 which happens to represent number 99.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fwrite()` takes strings. Try `chr(0x63)` if you want to write a `0x63` byte to the file.

Answer (score 4):

That's because fwrite() expects a string as its second argument. Try doing this instead:

```
fwrite($fpr, chr(0x63));
```

chr(0x63) returns a string with one character with ASCII value 0x63. (So it'll write the number 0x63 to the file.)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass an int to a function that accepts a string, so it's being converted to a string for you.

This will write what you want:

```
fwrite($fpr, "\x63");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to write binary to files, I would advise to use the `pack()` approach together with the file API.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719803/what-is-the-realtime-use-of-php-pack-and-unpack-function) for an example.