# What is the realtime use of PHP pack and unpack function?

Tags: php, file, file-io, pack

I saw some file generation codes which uses the pack function.

```
echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);
```

What this is doing exactly?

s signed short (always 16 bit, machine byte order)

I dont know why i am not able to understand this in realtime.
Am not asking a theoretical answer

When i execute the php , file got generated with some stange characters which is not identified by ms excel.

I just want to know the use of pack(), where to use and how to use?

Comment: When you need it, you'll know. Try to explain to a tribe of primitive, isolated humans why anyone "needs" air travel.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal your name says that you are from primitive tribe:-)

Comment: It's writing raw binary.  Examine the output with the commandline tool `od -x`, or a GUI "hex editor" to get a better idea of what the output of this line is.  In this case, this is apparently a BIFF8 header.  BIFF format details are available here: http://sc.openoffice.org/excelfileformat.pdf

Comment: My name predates your favourite television show, sir.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain me the pack() function in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987854/can-someone-explain-me-the-pack-function-in-php)

Comment: Real-time - real life ... whatever, as long as you keep it real, bro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pack` is generally used to generate raw binary data. For example, I saw it [used to generate zip files](http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4066.html) before [native functions/classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) were available in PHP for that.

Comment: To '-1' voter: any comment so I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

When would you need to use mysql_connect? When connecting to a MySQL database. Why? To connect to a MySQL database.

When you'll realize that you just got this bad-ass lines of Hex numbers and you need to convert them to ASCII, or when you want to generate a .exe from user input (don't), or when you want to write a Little-Endian encoder, or a bunch of other stuff, you'll use pack.

If you just want to understand what pack does, there's already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987854/can-someone-explain-me-the-pack-function-in-php) for it. But WHEN to use it? Well, when you want to pack data into a binary string.